# Custom button, that doesn't want to work properly when I am switching to another language

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am trying to create a button just like this one. This button already works fine in the English version, but when I switch to french, it breaks. The French text is much longer, and the button breaks into two separate parts. Any ideas how I can create a "responsive" (text size relative) button?
My code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="text-box text-center"><p>View By</p></div>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right small-tab" style="padding-right:20px">         
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li </li>
                <li </li>
                <li </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>



 .text-box {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 27px;
    min-width: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 1px 0 0 0;
    margin-right: -1px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 225px;

    p {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
}



 .small-tab {
    .btn:first-child {
        border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    }
}

    .btn-group.open .btn.dropdown-toggle {
    background-color:#1388e2;
}

.btn {
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#46a9f8;
    border: none;   
}
    .btn:hover {
        color:#ffffff;
        background-color:#128ded;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your CSS isn't valid, are you running it through a preprocessor of some sort?

Comment: Can you create an example on bootply or jsfiddle ?